# What's the distinctions of "starter", "appetizer", and "entree" when expressing a small dish that you eat at the beginning of a meal?

Tags: differences, dialects

As a foreign English learner, I always curious about the distinctions of quantity  when expressing a small dish that you eat at the beginning of a meal.
http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-entree-and-vs-appetizer/

Comment: Hello Ethan! What information  did you find about these words in the dictionary?

Comment: I am not sure about an "entee", but an _entrée_ is a main course.

Comment: @Cascabel: I think the meaning of "entree" may be regional. I read a rant about it some time back.

Comment: @sumelic I guess I should avoid mentioning _antipasto_.

Comment: @Cascabel: Now that I'm back on my computer, I've been able to dig up the rant I mentioned. It was "[Entrée Does Not Mean Main Course!](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/meg-hemphill/entree-does-not-mean-main-course_b_1415155.html)" by Meg Hemphill. She implies the usage is mainly (North) American, and the OED agrees: its original entry for the word defined it as a dish "served between the fish and the joint" (I wonder how many people have multi-course meals like that nowadays) and the meaning "The main dish or course of a meal" is given in a 2012 draft edition marked "Chiefly N. Amer."

Comment: @sumelic Well color me North American. I suppose the OP should have specified by region; or at least a good answer will have to make those fine distinctions.

Comment: The North American use of entrée has always bothered me, especially because the original French meaning translates pretty clearly as "starter". Why can't we just say "main course"?

Comment: @Rocky Clearly it was an evil plot designed by snooty _maitre d's_ to keep us in our place no matter how much French we studied.

Comment: @Rocky - I thought the people who say *entrée* work at restaurants where an appetizer is not commonly part of the meal.  But I'm not a big restaurant-goer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Entrée" is regional. In England (and the English speaking world in general), it means the same as appetizer or starter. In the US and Canada, however, "entrée" means "main course". So North America is the exception.

"Starter" is more commonly used in British English and "appetizer" in North America, but they are synonyms and commonly understood.

Source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entr%C3%A9e)

Comment: "North America is the exception"?

Comment: Yeah, turns out we're not the centre of the universe :-)

Comment: I think what @aparente001 was referrring to was that in sheer numbers North America would seem to be the majority, not the exception.